# How to read 3 lines of a text file c#

Tags: c#, linq

I designed a program that reads a specific line of the text file but I want to
To read 3 lines and put them in the text box, for example, read lines `1`, `3` and `5` only from the text file. Thank you

This is the code I want to modify to read *more* than one line, not a *single* line

```
  private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        string line = File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName).Skip(2).FirstOrDefault();
        TextBox1.Text = line;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `Where`, i.e.

```
string[] lines = File
  .ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName)
  .Take(5) // optimization: we want 5 lines at most 
  .Where((line, index) => index == 0 || index == 2 || index == 4)
  .ToArray();
```

please, note that `index` is *zero* based (*1st* line has `index == 0`). In case of arbitrary indexes

```
HashSet<int> indexes = new HashSet<int>() {0, 2, 4};

string[] lines = File
  .ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName)
  .Take(indexes.Max() + 1) // optimization 
  .Where((line, index) => indexes.Contains(index))
  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

System.IO.File.ReadLines() returns an IEnumerable.

On that, you can do things like use .ElementAt(index) to get specific lines, though keep in mind the first line is an index of 0. So you would actually want indices 0, 2, and 4 for for your example.

Comment: Using `ElementAt` on the `IEnumerable` from `ReadLines` is going to result in opening and reading from the file each time you call it.

Answer (score 0):

`Where` and `Contains` are your friends here :

`Where` has an overload that takes the index of array as 2nd argument.

```
var indicesToTake = new int[] { 1, 3, 5 };
string[] lines = File
  .ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName)
  .Where((x, i) => indicesToTake.Contains(i))
  .ToArray();

string fullText = string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, lines); // and TextBox1.Text = fullText;
// or TextBox1.Lines = lines
```

you can also build the range of indices you want with linq, for instance if you want all odd indices between 1 and 100 :

```
var indicesToTake = Enumerable.Range(100).Where(i => i % 2 == 1);
```

As Dmitry Bychenko wrote, you can use other optimization tricks (`Take` to avoid checking all the array, especially if you want lines up to low index 10, but you much more lines after the last)

Comment: Thank you, but when I press the button, I want to show the lines in the text box

Comment: @mazentq since this returns an array of `string`, we can combine them using `string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines )`

Comment: @mazentq You can use `TextBox1.Lines = lines`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton even simpler, indeed

Comment: Thank you I have been working successfully Thank you very much

Comment: @mazentq Glad to help, please don't forget to upvote all answers you think have been useful, and accept one ;)

Comment: @Pac0  Can you add a comment under each of the lines that you have displayed in the text box? Thank you